# How to change ampersand's font in formula?

Tags: fonts, ampersand

I have the formula, which contains ampersand symbol:

```
$x_1\&x_2$
```

But ampersand symbol is too bold. How to fix it?
[image]

```
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}                    % Загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}    % Свойства шрифтов по умолчанию



\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt, font=small, justification=centerlast}

\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize{A4}                                           % Размер листа
\setmarginsrb{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{0pt}{0mm}{0pt}{0mm}       % Размеры полей
\sloppy

%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление

%% Номера формул
%\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.

%% Шрифты
\usepackage{euscript}    % Шрифт Евклид
\usepackage{mathrsfs}    % Красивый матшрифт
\usepackage{mathtext}    % Русские буквы в формулах
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Первый абзац тоже с красной строки
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   % Задаёт основной шрифт документа
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}

%%% Работа с картинками
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Для вставки рисунков
\graphicspath{{Images/}}  % папки с картинками
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt} % Отступ рамки \fbox{} от рисунка
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt} % Толщина линий рамки \fbox{}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Обтекание рисунков и таблиц текстом
\captionsetup{figurewithin=none} % Сквозная нумерация рисунков
\usepackage{tikz}

%%% Работа с таблицами
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs} % Дополнительная работа с таблицами
\usepackage{longtable}  % Длинные таблицы
\usepackage{multirow} % Слияние строк в таблице

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Колонтитулы
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}  % Толщина линейки, отчеркивающей верхний колонтитул
    \lfoot{}
    \rfoot{}
    \rhead{}
    \chead{}
    \lhead{}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filcenter}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
    {8pt}
    {\bfseries}{}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\large\bfseries}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}
    {1em}{}

% Настройка вертикальных и горизонтальных отступов
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{8pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{\parindent}{*4}{*4}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{\parindent}{*4}{*4}

% Оглавление

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace{0.38\textwidth} \bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em}
% \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\mbox{}\hfill \\ \mbox{}\hfill{\footnotesize Стр.}\vspace{-2.5em}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername} }
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\hspace{31pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\hspace{11pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\cftparskip}{-1mm}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % задать глубину оглавления — до subsection включительно

\newcommand{\empline}{\mbox{}}
\newcommand{\likechapterheading}[1]{ 
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{#1}
    \end{center}
}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{2}
    \newcommand{\l@likechapter}[2]{{\bfseries\@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{0pt}{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\likechapter}[1]{    
    \likechapterheading{#1}    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{likechapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\usepackage{cite} % Работа с библиографией
%\usepackage[superscript]{cite} % Ссылки в верхних индексах
%\usepackage[nocompress]{cite} % 
\usepackage{csquotes} % Еще инструменты для ссылок
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about your document setup. In particular, which text and math fonts do you load (and how are they loaded)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted a lot of code unrelated to math fonts, but not enough to actually run your example. I made a document up here.

[image]

`\&` isn't really set up as a math command so is most likely using your body font (which seems to be Times) not the fonts used in the math expression.

I give some alternatives here, I think the first is essentially what you have although the font choices seem to be different (perhaps set in the code you did not show)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}                    % Загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}    % Свойства шрифтов по умолчанию


%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление

%% Номера формул
%\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.

%% Шрифты
\usepackage{euscript}    % Шрифт Евклид
\usepackage{mathrsfs}    % Красивый матшрифт
\usepackage{mathtext}    % Русские буквы в формулах

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   % Задаёт основной шрифт документа
\usepackage{color}


% Оглавление

\showoutput
\begin{document}

% times roman & in cm math
$1 + x + \& + y$

% cm & in cm math
\mathcode`\&=\numexpr\mathcode`\1-`\1+`\&\relax

$1 + x + \& + y$


% whatever you want
\let\oldamp\&
\protected\def\&{\ifmmode\hbox{\tiny\textcolor{red}{\oldamp}}\else\oldamp\fi}

$1 + x + \& + y$


\end{document}
```